# Angular2 : Prevent change function call when page loads

Tags: angular

I am learning Angular 2. I am trying to implement autosave functionality using **(change)** event. Like this

```
<div>
    <md-input class="ctrl" [(ngModel)]="first" (blur)="saveItemInfo()"></md-input>
</div>
<div>
    <md2-autocomplete [items]="items" item-text="name" item-value="value" [(ngModel)]="second" [disabled]="disabled"
        (change)="saveItemInfo()">
    </md2-autocomplete>
</div>
<div>
    <md-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="third" color="primary" (change)="saveItemInfo()"></md-slide-toggle>
</div>
```

Here the problem is, change event is firing even when page loads. So that it is making so many api calls. Any other way to do this?

Comment: Do a check in `saveItemInfo` to see if anything actually changed.

Comment: Try to change `(change)` to `(keyup)` and check if it works for you.

Comment: @micronyks, (keyup) not working for **md2-autocomplete**. It is not firing event when change occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a private variable like `_second` and on every `(change)` event check if anything changed:

- If yes, set the private variable to the new value and call your API methods.
- If not, do nothing